# mongodb debugging - ReferenceError: console is not defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-shell

I got `js` file to run within `mongodb` where I got `console.log` expression for debugging:

```
use test;
db.city.find().snapshot().forEach(function(city){
    var Pos = city.Pos;

    if (Pos) 
    {
        longLat = Pos.split(" ");
        console.log("longLat");  // for debugging ----------------------------  
        console.log(longLat);

        lon = longLat[0];
        lat = longLat[1];

        if (lon && lat)
        {
            lon = parseFloat(lon);
            lat = parseFloat(lat);
            longLat = [lon, lat];
            city.longLat = longLat;

        }

    }
    db.orgs.save(city);

})
```

When I run it...

```
mongo < /path/to/this/js/file.js
```

... I got error in the output:

```
ReferenceError: console is not defined
```

Is there any way to log intermediate results for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `print` or `printjson` methods instead. These are used to emit just like console.log() within the shell:

```js
    if (Pos) 
    {
        longLat = Pos.split(" ");
        print("longLat");  // for debugging ----------------------------  
        printjson(longLat);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your code you could do this.

```
var console = {};
console.log = print;
```

Then when your code calls console.log, it's actually calling print().
But this is not a true replacement because it doesn't handle printing of objects like NodeJS's console.log() does.  For example,

```
console.log('abc', { 'field1' : 123 });
// In NodeJS output is: abc { field1: 123 }
// In Mongo print output is: abc [object Object]
```

A more full featured implementation would handle this.
This article [Taking Over console.log](http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/) might help if you wanted to create a more full featured implementation.